# Using materialize css with ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, materialize

I'd like to import materialize's files (installed via bower) in my ember-cli project;
I've tried almost all I've found googling around but I'm still not able to make it work;

materialize is in bower_components/materialize directory;

What I'm doing now is:
inside styles/app.scss

```
@import "bower_components/materialize/sass/materialize";
```

inside ember-cli-build.js

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
var pickFiles = require('broccoli-static-compiler');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
    var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {

    });


    var materializeFonts = pickFiles('bower_components/materialize/font/roboto', {
        srcDir: '/',
        destDir: '/font/roboto'
    });


    return app.toTree([materializeFonts]);
};
```

Once I start with "ember server" I still get the errors in console 404 not found for roboto fonts;

Also I can't understand how to import the materialize's js;

can someone explain to me how to get rid of this?
(I've seen a package called ember-cli-materialize, but I'd like to understand how to make this work manually, since this can be helpful also with other libraries).

Comment: May I suggest https://github.com/mike-north/ember-cli-materialize

Comment: you are surely right, but as I wrote I'd like to understand why I'm not able to make it works, since it can be useful also for other libraries; and also I prefer not to use many external "wrappers" for libraries, since It is usaully better to rely on the original repository only (in order to have always the latest release etc...)

Comment: Well, I would suggest using an addon 90% of the time. If the addon is out of date you could always update it by submitting a pull request or just forking it to match your needs. The Ember ecosystem gives you a myriad of addons developed by the community and it would be a shame to dismiss all the work you could save yourself from.

You can also look at the source and see what the addon is doing: https://github.com/mike-north/ember-cli-materialize/blob/aa25e387ec54fffaa42c7bf7c0792decb1ed7a2b/index.js

Comment: ok that's a fair point ;)

Comment: If you choose to over-rely on add-ons make sure you are wearing very high wading boots.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing [broccoli-merge-trees](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli-merge-trees) to merge the app tree and fonts tree together. I started using [Broccoli Funnel](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli-funnel) instead of broccoli-static-compiler and broccoli-merge-trees to bring additional dependencies into the dist directory.

I'm using Materialize in a project and have it working as follows:

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/broccoli/ember-app');
var Funnel = require('broccoli-funnel');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
    var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {});
    var materializeFonts = new Funnel('bower_components/materialize/font/roboto', {
        srcDir: '/',
        include: ['*.woff', '*.ttf', '*.woff2'],
        destDir: '/font/roboto'
    });

    return app.toTree([materializeFonts]);
};
```

And then in my `styles/app.scss`:

```
@import "bower_components/materialize/sass/materialize.scss";
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are using ember-cli-sass. So why not configure a new include path for additional scss files.

```js
var app = new EmberApp({
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [
      'bower_components/foundation/scss'
    ]
  }
});
```

Now all your @import statements will work.

If you want to import fonts, use the app.import function.

```js
app.import('bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf', {
 destDir: 'fonts'
});
```